# Unusual behaviour of ng-checked / checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

```
<input class="ML1" type="checkbox"  ng-checked="item.ph_comp_change"  ng-model="item.ph_comp_change"  ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```

This makes an input checkbox, but the problem is I need to uncheck it 2 times, in order to remove check sign from it. But if I remove `ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"`, it works fine.

Working JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14616/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put condition on ng-checked

ng-checked="item.ph_comp_change === 1"

it will work.

Comment: It worked!! :) I'll accept  your answer after 6-7 min.

Comment: @anita you are encouraging people to wrong use of `ng-selected`

Comment: @pankajparkar ng-checked not ng-selected .Anyways if situation required then ng-checked is needed.. and in this case yes we might ignore ng-checked. But we dont know about the whole structure . Only one line of code is given so without knowing the whole structure , I posted what i felt right. Just in some line of code you cant decide that its wrong use or right use.

Comment: my bad it should `ng-checked`.I'd don't prefer to use it..As his fiddle show you his code..still you are thinking like that, I can't do anything about it. Its very bad idea to use `ng-checked`

Comment: @pankajparkar Yes, actually. If I don't use, next time when page reloads, the check-box don't come selected(although ng-model contains value "1"). That's the only reason I accepted this answer. I don't know why that was happening ,but to use  ng-checked  or not ,depends upon the whole structure of app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so there is need of `ng-checked`, on change of `ng-model` value angular will update value for you & you will see the effect in scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app>
     <h2>Todo</h2>

    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <div style="float:left;">--->{{item.ph_comp_change}}
            <input class="ML1" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.ph_comp_change" 
            ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" /> 
            <span ng-bind-html="ph_comp_change_label"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14619/)

Comment: That's even greater help!! :)

Comment: @RishiPrakash really you shouldn't use `ng-checked` as angular already going to do check & uncheck itself

Comment: @RishiPrakash did you think that your accepted answer is correct way? what you think?

Comment: deeply appreciate you help :)